# Is "get off this station" instead of "get off at this station" not gramatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Can you write get off this station or get off the next station without using the preposition at?

Comment: "Get off this station" is grammatically correct.  But it does not mean "Get off at this station."

Comment: It means "leave the station", not "leave the train at the station".

Comment: @Kate Oh the joys of ambiguity – I immediately thought, “Why would I leave the train at the station? It’ll just block the rails for any other trains coming in!”.

Comment: If King Kong comes to town and starts jumping up and down on your favorite Kwik Trip then saying "Get off this station!" would be appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Get off this station* means that *this station* is the direct object of the verb phrase "get off." One is thus leaving the station. Compare to this line ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jw3PJftd-_E)) in the 1997 film Air Force One:

> Get off my plane

where the bad guy departs the plane after Harrison Ford compels him to.

*Get off at this station* means that *this station* is the object of *at*, and specifies where the person will depart something else (a train, a vehicle, a bus). Where will he *get off at*? *This station*. One is arriving at the station, not departing the station.

Going back to Air Force One, if Harrison Ford had said,

> Get off at my plane

the scene wouldn't make sense in context, but might make sense if he were instructing someone to get off another vehicle when it passed by his plane at the airport.